# Creating Golf Shot Dispersion Chart with Semi-Circular Y-Axis in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts, chart.js

I'm working on a golf shot dispersion chart project in React.js, and I'm looking for guidance on how to create a chart where the y-axis is semi-circular, similar to the shape of a golf course range. To provide a visual reference, here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I've already implemented the basic scatter plot using a library like Chart.js, but I'm unsure about how to customize the y-axis to make it semi-circular and match the shape of a golf course range. I believe this unique y-axis shape will provide a more accurate representation of shot dispersion.

Could someone please provide insights, code snippets, or guidance on how to achieve this semi-circular y-axis effect in React.js, possibly using Chart.js or any other libraries that can help accomplish this?

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's always the solution to draw everything in cartesian coordinates, including the grid lines - as part of the data and not as axes.